# Game resizing on my phone but looks fine on the simulator

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When I start my game on the simulator within xcode the game shows up as intended, but when I start up the game via my phone it shrinks after the initial splash screen. How do I stop this from happening? What's the cause of this?

Comment: Disregard this, I found the source of the problem: it's to do with the retina display, I commented this out within the AppDelegate: 
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
  CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
and it is fine now.